# How to get n last elements from list in Django template

Tags: django, list, templates

I have an image slider inside my website and I want it to display n (or in my case 3) `preview_image` of the latest posts.

In `models.py`:

```
 preview_image = models.ImageField(default="img/news/default_preview.png", upload_to="img/news")
```

In `views.py`:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        "posts": list(Post.objects.all())
    }
    return render(request, "news/news_home.html", context)
```

In `news_home.html`:

```
    ...
    <img src="{{ posts.1.preview_image.url }}" alt="">
    ...
```

This works for specific post, but I want to select the latest(last one) in the list, so far I tried:

```
  <img src="{{ posts|slice:'-1:'.preview_image.url }}" alt="">
  <img src="{{ posts|slice:'-2:-1'.preview_image.url }}" alt="">
  <img src="{{ posts|slice:'-3:-2'.preview_image.url }}" alt="">
```

But I get an error:

```
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '.preview_image.url' from 'posts|slice:'-1:'.preview_image.url'
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to show preview image of the latest post? Just add it in context using `Post.objects.all().last()`

Comment: @Crosby not just the latest, the 3 most recent, like `posts[-1].preview_image.url`, `posts[-2].preview_image.url` and `posts[-3].preview_image.url`. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: Pass all of them in context: `latest_posts = Post.objects.order_by('-pk')[:3]`

Comment: That's it. Thank you. I was trying to "get away" with negative indices in the template, while this is much more smoother and simpler.